# Executing multiple line shell command in php

Tags: php, shell, exec

I'm trying to execute a shell command from php using the `exec` command

The following command works

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

but I need to execute the following shell command

```
cat > /var/www/myfolder/abc.txt
hi
hello
welcome
```

the problem is that the above shell command has to be executed in multiplelines. The words "hi", "hello", "welcome" are dynamic and come from php variables. Is there a workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a multiline shell command in php:

```
passthru("bash <<'END'
        echo \"executed in new bash session\";
        pwd;
        whoami;
        exit;
        END
");
```

This way you could for example connect to a ssh server using php and then execute some commands there

I don't understand what you mean by `cat > abc.txt`. This command will empty the file.

Comment: the cat command is used to write content to a file
in terminal when I provide 
cat >abc.txt
hI
hello
(ctrl+D)
a file is created with hi hello as its contents